# Post edits history

Tags: discussion

I'm sure this topic has been previously discussed, but the search force is not strong with me today.

I've noticed a couple of times already, that my questions always seem to be edited.

While in my first questions the edits were rather obvious, as I had missed formatting or the likes, in later questions I find it hard to track what has been changed.

Is there anyway to see the history of edits in your own questions/answers?

If yes, please tell me how, if not, was this a design option or would this be a new functionality to be requested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just click the "timeline" link below any post to see the history of its edits/revisions.

Comment: Got it! I would expect it to be linking to the editor's profile page, as it does with the original poster :-S Anyway, found the "timeline", and reviewed the edits. No "hi", and No "Thanks" on posts :-). Thanks HedgeMage